# Will food allergy rashes eventually stop appearing?

Tags: nutrition, allergy, rash

I've recently noticed that after eating certain food, I develop a minor allergic reaction in form of a small red rash or two, anywhere on my body.

The allergic reaction is in my opinion very minor, developing almost mosquito-byte sized rashes. Besides being annoying visually, they do not irritate me.

Since these dishes are a big part of my diet, and a big part of my culture in general, I do not want to give up this diet.

My question is is it possible that body will eventually get used to this diet again, stopping the rashes from appearing? Is there any research on this?

Comment: There's no way to know. You might become desensitized, stay the same, or get worse. All can occur.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think that writing an answer that explains that any of the three is possible is a good strategy here - the question is not "personal medical advice" to somebody who thinks that one of the three is the guaranteed course for everybody.

Comment: @rumtscho - The OP is asking what will happen to *his* rashes. That answer is not possible to give. I'm not opposed to someone else answering if they don't think it's impossible to say.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Personal medical advice is strictly off-topic here, and your question was impossible to answer because no one can predict body's future reactions. I took the liberty of editing it to try and make it more on-topic and prevent it from being closed, since it seems very interesting. If you disagree with the edit you can always roll back (you'll find this option in the edit history). Thanks!